# Couchbase XDCR getting duplicate replication id

Tags: couchbase

In createReplication call keep getting same replication id all the time. How to get unique Id? The requirement is need to check metrics per replication created. Say we are programmatically creating replication aim to monitor it by periodically call stats API and changes_left is 0 we are stopping replication programmatically by calling cancelreplication.
The issue with couchbase behavior is getting the same replication ID all the time. How the replication id is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication ID is ultimately composed in the following format:

```
<Remote Cluster UUID>/<SourceBucketName>/<TargetBucketName>
```

XDCR internally has a randomly generated Internal ID to differentiate between instances, but it is not exposed to the outside world.